# How to group/batch events with aggregator in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a channel whose payload is different POJOs that implement an interface called `Event`.

```
public interface Event {
    String getEventType();
}
```

Events of many event types are added to channel one by one using a gateway. I want to group the events based on event type and call a service activator. The service have the following signature.

```
void processEventsInBatch(String eventType, List<Event> events);
```

It is important to get multiple events which belong to the same event type in the list to process them in batch and reduce multiple calls to external services.

How to achieve this with spring integration?

Comment: Posting this question and the answer I came up with as I struggled a bit with this problem. I'm sure there will be better approaches to solve this; which I'm expecting as alternative answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregator in spring-integration uses correlation-id header (by default) to identify different messages in the same group. So the first step is to get eventType as correlation-id header. Later we can get this header as eventType param in the service activator as the correlation-id header will be present for the groups created by aggregator. This can be done by the following xml config

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:correlation-id expression="payload.getEventType()"/>
<int:header-enricher>
```

Now the aggregator can be used as shown below.

```
<int:aggregator release-strategy-expression="size() >= 25"
                group-timeout="5000"
                expire-group-upon-completion="true"
                send-partial-results-on-expiry="true" />
```

The above aggregator will send a group when it have at least 25 events in one group or it waited for 5 seconds. We can adjust the first two parameters to control how big we want the list to be and how much delay we want to introduce. The `expire-group-upon-completion` attribute is required to make sure that the aggregator continue to create new groups with same correlation-id. And the `send-partial-results-on-expiry` is required to make sure that if we get less than 25 events in 5 seconds, then the aggregator will send a group with what it have.

Comment: Your understanding and answer to the problem is just brilliant. Not sure what is your doubt... Just accept your own answer and go ahead with development!